# Create new nested column within dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have the following

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'data': [1,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'data': [4,5,6]})
df = pd.concat([df1,df2], keys=['hello','world'], axis=1)
```

What is the "proper" way of creating a new nested column (say, `df['world']['data']*2`) within the `hello` column? I have tried `df['hello']['new_col'] = df['world']['data']*2` but this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tuple`s for select and set `MultiIndex`:

```
df[('hello','new_col')] = df[('world','data')]*2
print (df)
  hello world   hello
   data  data new_col
0     1     4       8
1     2     5      10
2     3     6      12
```

Selecting like `df['world']['data']` is not recommended - [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy), because possible chained indexing.

Comment: Thanks for this, can you also explain the difference between `['hello']['new_col']` and `[('hello','new_col')]` when assigning columns to a df?